# Get diff attribute in ansible file module

Tags: ansible

I am having below task in my playbook

```yaml
- name: remove
  file:
    dest: '/folder1/{{item}}'
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{file_list}}"
  register: result

- debug: 
    msg: "{{item}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{result.results|map(attribute='diff')|list}}"
```

When the all the files in the `{{file_list}}` get removed I am able to debug all the diff attribute in the debug module in correct format. But if the `{{ file_list }}` has a wrong file name I am getting Ansible undefined in the `debug` msg and not able to print in correct format. How to print only the diff variables of the defined items.

Answer (score 0):

first, why you use `dest` parameters ? you can use `path` parameter.

when the file doesn't exist, the return result item don't have diff key.
thiis is the differnce with existing file and non existing file:

```
"msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "diff": {
                    "after": {
                        "path": "debug.txt",
                        "state": "absent"
                    },
                    "before": {
                        "path": "debug.txt",
                        "state": "file"
                    }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_diff_peek": null,
                        "_original_basename": null,
                        "access_time": null,
                        "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": true,
                        "force": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "modification_time": null,
                        "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "owner": null,
                        "path": "debug.txt",
                        "recurse": false,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "state": "absent",
                        "unsafe_writes": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "debug.txt",
                "path": "debug.txt",
                "state": "absent"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And

```
"msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_diff_peek": null,
                        "_original_basename": null,
                        "access_time": null,
                        "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": true,
                        "force": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "modification_time": null,
                        "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "owner": null,
                        "path": "debug.txt",
                        "recurse": false,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "state": "absent",
                        "unsafe_writes": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "debug.txt",
                "path": "debug.txt",
                "state": "absent"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the file don't exist, the result item don't have a `diff` key. So you have an exception. You can debug the return based on existing or not of `diff`key.

```
- name: remove
  file:
    path: '/folder1/{{item}}'
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{file_list}}"
  register: result

- debug: 
    msg: "{{item.diff}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{result.results}}"
  when: item.diff is defined
```

Comment: Not able to get the ouput using condition item is defined or item.diff is defined

Comment: Change the with_items: ```with_items:
    - "{{result.results}}"```@Newbee

Comment: @Newbee, i change the solution to adapt it. read it again